# how to get ride of faulty 301/2 redirects?

Tags: apache, http, .htaccess, redirect

In my .htaccess I set a (couple) of 301 redirects. They are picked up only to create a infinite loop.

For example I set the following code:

```
Redirect 301 / http://example.com/nl
```

Which keeps the browser redirecting to example.com/nl -> example.com/nl/nl -> example.com/nl/nl/nl -> example.com/nl/nl/nl/nl -> etc.

Another one which keeps prepending www. to the domain name (www.www.www.www.www.example.com).

And a few other I set up trying to fix the mess. Of course the first thing I did was to revert .htaccess to the original format. However all redirects are still in effect! (on multiple browser/machines/"privacy browser"/IPS).

For testing tried adding this:

```
Redirect 301 /test http://www.google.com
```

This sends the browser to google if you go to example.com/test.

But if I change it to

```
Redirect 301 /test http://www.drupal.org
```

or

```
Redirect 302 /test http://www.drupal.org
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com [L,R=301]
```

or
remove the code completely.

It still keeps going to google instead of drupal.org.

How do I get rid of these faulty redirects? :(

Answer (score 1):

Since 301 is the code for Permanent Redirection, it would make sense that it is somehow cached. Try clearing your cache and see if the problem persists.

Comment: But cached where? It's not in my browser, because after removing it from .htaccess I tried different machines/browsers and they all have the same problem.